# Is there a good solution to connect Segger J-Link to a solderless breadboard?

Tags: connector, breadboard, j-link

I am working on a project where I created different prototypes on different solderless breadboards. To program and debug the used MCU using SWD, I just use male jumper wires, from the j-link connector to the pins of the MCU on the breadboard.

Now, I would like to cycle through the different iterations of the project, which are on different solderless breadboards. But every time I have to carefully reconnect the jumper wires from one breadboard to another.

**Is there any better solution to this?** So I can faster and especially safer switch the J-Link connection between the different solderless breadboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

[image]

http://www.technologicalarts.ca/shop/store/details/247/56/adapters/ribbon-cable/idc-ribbon-cable-to-breadboard-adapter,-20-pin.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be to make an adapter board to plug the cable into a breadboard, along these lines:

[image]

If you're wondering, that board is a [Pi Cobbler from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/914). It's got the wrong number of pins for a 2x10 ARM JTAG cable, but it wouldn't be hard to design your own board for this.

Comment: This looks promising, it would be a solution. So there is no ready made product with the 2x10 pin layout?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but it'd be very easy to design and get produced. If you've never designed a PCB before, this would be a great introduction.

Comment: Agreed with @duskwuff; it would be a nice simple project to learn PCB tools, the manufacturing process, and hand soldering. A good one for either OSHPark or dirtyPCBs, as I'm sure the boards would be super cheap even at low quantities.